# Open read-only file on OSX

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, read-write

There is a file in my `/opt/local/include` folder on OSX that I wish to edit.

This is currently set to 'Read only'. So, to allow me to edit, I have selected `get info`, then under `sharing and permissions` I have added myself, and given me the privileges `Read and write`. However, I now open the file and am still unable to save it.

What do I need to do to allow me to edit and save this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an editor that, when saving, replaces the file instead of changing its contents.

Give yourself permissions for the parent folder and you'll be able to save, or use another editor.

Comment: Yes, changing the folder permissions did the trick. How bizarre.

Comment: @Bill It's actually a reasonable way to handle saving files, permissions aside. If saving fails halfway through writing the file, you'll have neither the old nor the new data anymore otherwise.